# Kernel Module to reboot linux

Tags: kernel-module, reboot

How can I EXPORT_SYMBOL in my dynamic module to reboot my linux system.

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(register_restart_handler);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(unregister_restart_handler);
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(kernel_restart);
```

how to use `struct notifier_block` and `char *cmd` in `void kernel_restart(char *cmd)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Found the solution just add kernel_restart(NULL). No need to register handler.

```
   int init_module(void)
{

    mdelay(5000);

    kernel_restart(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```